# How to trigger default rendering in Sharepoint 2013 List View via JS Link

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint-2013, jslink

I'm building a custom layout for a SharePoint list via JS Link... 
At the moment I'm rendering all by myself, but for some more complex items (Taxonomy, URLs, etc.) it would be great to be able to trigger the custom rendering of SharePoint.

Is this possible somehow for single field types?

```
var csListView = csListView || {};

csListView.ListBody = '<div class="datagrid"><table><thead>{LIST_HEADER}</thead>{LIST_BODY}<tfoot><tr><td colspan="{FIELD_COUNT}"><div class="paging">{PAGINATION}</div></td></tr></tfoot></table></div>';
csListView.HeaderRow = '<tr>{HEADER_ITEMS}</tr>';
csListView.HeaderItem = '<th>{HEADER_ITEM}</th>';
csListView.BodyRow = '<tr class="{ALT_CLASS}">{LIST_ITEMS}</tr>';
csListView.BodyItem = '<td>{LIST_ITEM}</td>';

csListView.CustomizeFieldRendering = function ()
{
    var fieldJsLinkOverride = {};
    fieldJsLinkOverride.Templates = {};
    fieldJsLinkOverride.Templates.Body = csListView.RenderBody;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(fieldJsLinkOverride);
};

csListView.RenderBody = function (ctx) {
    var colspan = ctx.ListSchema.Field.length;
    var html = '';
    var itemHtml = '';
    var itemsHtml = '';
    var rowHtml = '';
    var bodyHtml = '';
    var paginationHtml = '';
    var headerItemsHtml = '';
    var headerHtml = '';

    //Render Header fields
    for (var i = 0; i < ctx.ListSchema.Field.length; i++) {
        var sortUrl =   location.search + '?SortField=' + ctx.ListSchema.Field[i].RealFieldName  + '&SortDir=Desc';//ctx.HttpRoot + ctx.listUrlDir + '/&' + ctx.ListSchema.FieldSortParam
        var item = '<a href="' +  sortUrl + '">' + ctx.ListSchema.Field[i].DisplayName + '</a>';
        headerItemsHtml += csListView.HeaderItem.replace('{HEADER_ITEM}', ctx.ListSchema.Field[i].DisplayName);
    }
    headerHtml = csListView.HeaderRow.replace('{HEADER_ITEMS}', headerItemsHtml);

    //Go through all rows
    for (var i = 0; i < ctx.ListData.Row.length; i++) {
        var cssClass = (i % 2 == 0) ? 'alt' : '';

        //Go through all fields
        itemsHtml = '';
        for (var j = 0; j < ctx.ListSchema.Field.length; j++) {
            var item = csListView.renderField(ctx, ctx.ListSchema.Field[j], ctx.ListData.Row[i]);

            itemHtml = csListView.BodyItem.replace('{LIST_ITEM}',item);
            itemsHtml += itemHtml;
        }       
        rowHtml = csListView.BodyRow.replace('{LIST_ITEMS}',itemsHtml);
        rowHtml = rowHtml.replace('{ALT_CLASS}', cssClass);
        bodyHtml += rowHtml;
    }

    html = csListView.ListBody.replace('{LIST_BODY}', bodyHtml);
    html = html.replace('{PAGINATION}', renderPaging(ctx));
    html = html.replace('{FIELD_COUNT}', colspan);
    html = html.replace('{LIST_HEADER}', headerHtml);

    return html;
};


csListView.renderField = function (ctx, fieldData, rowData) {
    return rowData[fieldData.RealFieldName];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a the view of a field you could use this

```js
var ctx = {};
ctx.Templates = {};
ctx.Templates.Fields = {'ColumnName': { 'View' : '<b><#=ctx.CurrentItem.ColumnName#></b>' }};
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
```

Does that answer your question?